# Search different words between two files

Tags: python-3.x

I have two files (txt), for examle FILE A and FILE B and i want to
find all the words in FILE A that exist in FILE B,

**for example if file A is :**

```
HIS HOUSE IS VERY SMALL
```

**and file B is**

```
HIS DOG IS VERY NICE
```

I want to write a program that show me that HOUSE is not
in file B.

I thought to use the SPLIT command and looping over the file
but since I do not know the python well, does anyone can help me
if there is another command that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better solution, but this one below will solve your problem.

```
import re

def is_letter(s):
    return re.match('[a-z]|[A-Z]$', s)

def words_only(s):
    for i, x in enumerate(s):
        if not is_letter(x):
            s = s[:i] + s[i:].replace(x, ' ')
    s = re.sub( '\s+', ' ', s).strip().upper().split(' ')
    return s

file_a = words_only(open('file_a.txt', 'r').read())
file_b = words_only(open('file_b.txt', 'r').read())

for x in file_a:
    if x not in file_b:
        print(x)
```

### file_a.txt

HIS DOG IS VERY SMALL.

His wife is very nice.

### file_b.txt

HIS DOG IS VERY NICE.

He is very ugly.